# How to count truncated distinct dates in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with users and log_date_time of an application and I would like to show how many users used an application at a specific date and time. The column with LOG_DATETM looks like this:

`2015-04-30 11:20:31`

so I truncate the date to show me just an hour on a specific day. I do this:

```
select USER_NAME AS userName, TRUNC(LOG_DATETM, 'HH24') AS dateTime from CBB_APP_USAGE
```

result:

```
CT5517  2015-07-06 06:00:00
CT5517  2015-07-06 06:00:00
CT5517  2015-07-06 06:00:00
CU1441  2015-07-06 06:00:00
CU1441  2015-07-06 06:00:00
CU1441  2015-07-06 06:00:00
```

So I have two users that accessed the application at the same time (at 06:00:00) however what I need is to count the number of users that accessed this application at that time. This will show me the total usage at a specific time on a specific day and I will see the pick hours on the application throughout a month. How do I do that?

Comment: MySQL doesn't have a TRUNC function. But you could use GROUP By & the Count function

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the `trunc` function to truncate your datetime value and then use `count` with `group by` as usual.

This should work:

```
SELECT 
  TRUNC(LOG_DATETM, 'HH24') AS dateTime, 
  COUNT(DISTINCT USER_NAME) AS user_count
FROM CBB_APP_USAGE
GROUP BY TRUNC(LOG_DATETM, 'HH24');
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/99fa2/1)

Comment: I tried that but I got an error message: [Error Code: 904, SQL State: 42000]  ORA-00904: "DATE_FORMAT": incorrect identifier

Comment: @JędrekDomański Well, that would be because your apparently are using an Oracle database and not MySQL which you tagged the question as. If you replace the `dateformat` calls with the `TRUNC(LOG_DATETM, 'HH24')` you originally had it should work.

Comment: @JędrekDomański I've update my answer, please try it now.

Comment: I tried it but got an error [Error Code: 17439, SQL State: 99999]  Incorrect SQL type: sqlKind = UNINITIALIZED. I am using DB Virtualizer.

Comment: @JędrekDomański I'm sorry, but I have no idea why that happens as I have never used DB Virtualizer. The query itself should be correct (as shown in the SQL Fiddle) so it probably relates to the tool you use to execute it. Maybe the statement needs to be on a single line, or the quotes have to be escaped. I really don't know.